# getting jagged array from pagemethod into JavaScript

Tags: javascript, webmethod, pagemethods, jagged-arrays

I want to map a jagged array from pagemethod to JavaScript. Can anyone give me an example?

My jagged array from webmethod is:

```
<WebMethod()> _
   <ScriptMethod()> _
   Public Shared Function multiTable(ByVal para() As Object, ByVal spname As String) As Object(,)
    Dim dsrt As New DataSet, dbacc As New dataaccess
    dsrt = dbacc.retds1(spname, conn, para)
    Dim arr()() As Object = New Object(dsrt.Tables.Count - 1)() {}
    For i As Integer = 0 To dsrt.Tables.Count - 1
        arr(i) = New Object(dsrt.Tables(i).Columns.Count - 1) {}
        For j As Integer = 0 To dsrt.Tables(i).Columns.Count - 1
            arr(i)(j) = dsrt.Tables(i).Rows(i)(j)
        Next
    Next
End Function
```

I don't know how to translate it to JavaScript, but here is the code I've tried:

```
function success(result)
{
        var dsrp2 =[];
        if(result.length == 0)
        {
            dsrp2.length=0;
        }
        else
        {
            var ind = 0;var col=(result.length/2);  // i guess here only i should make change
            for (i=0;i<2;i++)
            {
            var data=[];
            for (j=0;j<col-1;j++)
            {
            data.push(result[ind]);
            ind++;
            }
            dsrp2.push(data);
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web method:

```
   <WebMethod()> _
   <ScriptMethod()> _
   Public Shared Function multiTable(ByVal para() As Object, ByVal spname As String) As Object()()
    Dim dsrt As New DataSet, dbacc As New dataaccess
    dsrt = dbacc.retds1(spname, conn, para)
    Dim arr()() As Object = New Object(dsrt.Tables.Count - 1)() {}
    For i As Integer = 0 To dsrt.Tables.Count - 1
        If dsrt.Tables(i).Rows.Count = 0 Then
            arr(i) = New Object(0)() {}
            Continue For
        Else
            arr(i) = New Object(dsrt.Tables(i).Columns.Count - 1) {}
            For j As Integer = 0 To dsrt.Tables(i).Columns.Count - 1
                arr(i)(j) = dsrt.Tables(i).Rows(0)(j)
            Next
        End If
    Next
    Return arr
  End Function
```

Javascript:

```
function success(result)
{
    var dsrp2 =new Array();
    dsrp2=result;
}
```